# Changing background color of a random Label

Tags: c#, random, label, tablelayoutpanel

I have created a 4x4 `TableLayoutPanel` filled with `Labels`. I would like to change `BackColor` of one random `Label` at a `Button_Click`. I'm not sure how do I have to do it.
Here is what I have so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Label[,] labelki = new Label[4, 4];
    Random los = new Random();
    Label wylosowanyLabel = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ZmienKolor()
    {
        int i = los.Next(1, 4);
        int j = los.Next(1, 4);
        wylosowanyLabel = labelki[i, j];
        wylosowanyLabel.BackColor = Color.Red; //I get a NullReferenceException here
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        ZmienKolor();
    }
}
```

Comment: What your problem exactly? Do you get any error message? You need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: You must attach a handler to your button click event. Add `buttonname.Click += (s, o) => { ChangeColor() };` after `InitializeComponenet();` in your form constructor.

Comment: The code you posted never populates the `labelki` array, therefor you get a null reference exception.

Comment: That was my problem really - 'connecting' created labels with the labelki array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that array, actually. you can use the TableLayoutPanel's Controls collection.
Try this:

```
// on the class level:
private int _LabelIndex;

// on the method you want to use for changing the backColor of a lable:


// you might want to change the backcolor of all other lables back to SystemColors.Control. 
// if that is the case, you can do something like this:
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().ForEach(c => c.BackColor = SystemColors.Control);

_LabelIndex = los.Next(0, this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[labelIndex].BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Create a common event handler for all labels inside the table lauout panel and get the index of the clicked control:

```
private void labels_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedLabel = (Label)sender;
    var index = this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.IndexOf(clickedLabel);
    if(index == _LabelIndex)
    {
        // used have clicked the red label.
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works how I wanted it to, so thanks for that. My problem now is how can I appeal to this label labelIndex from other method. Var variable can't be declared globally and I don't really know how I should do it otherwise. I want to check if user clicked this label, but I don't know how to send it to this checking method. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use a class level int variable for that.

Comment: But how do I compare the label clicked by user with the drawn one? Simple converting like `if (kliknietyLabel != Convert(Label,LabelIndex))` doesn't work

Comment: You can use the click event of the label to get it's index on the parent control. will edit my answer to include that when I have the time (probably only early Sunday).

Comment: Thanks for the advice and it would be awesome if you could do that ;)

Comment: thanks alot! I really appreciate your help. Hope I will be able to finish it by myself from now on ;)

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create an instance of your labels inside the array. You should create a new instance of each label first:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            labelki[i,j] = new Label();
        }
    }
}
```

Also in the `ZmienKolor` method you should generate random numbers between `0` and `4` instead of `1` and `4`:

```
int i = los.Next(0, 4);
int j = los.Next(0, 4);
```